# USB single chip ESD protector for two connectors through a power switch

Tags: usb, esd

How to connect USB protector against Vdd line with a single chip ESD protector?

I have a USB power switch for VBUS (MAX1564ETE+) and I plan to use DALC208SC6 for both USB connectors. I connected temporarily V+ of protector to main 5V (which is before USB MAX1564 power switch) but I am not sure this is right.

More appropriate in my case seems to keep V+ of DALC208SC6 connected to a zener, but what value?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks for advices.

Comment: To the clamping value, for example 5.1V.

Answer (score 2):

The function of the ESD protection IC is to short high voltage spikes. If you reverse-bias a diode over its reverse breakdown voltage it will start conducting. Positive spikes will short to GND and negative spikes will short to V+. You can connect V+ to the 5V rail. Also use a 5.1V zener from Vcc to gnd to clamp the voltage.

Comment: Make sense except "negative will go to Vdd". For GND, this is the return path for originating ESD pulse. Shorting to Vdd will not hurt devices connected to +5V, especially in my case where there is a power switch between "return path" on Vdd rail? Just asking :)

Answer (score 2):

USB bus needs <3pF protection to not interfere with signal BW. As such the DAL part is a diode half bridge tied to 0V =Vref1 & 5V =Vref2 with a choke and cap. Since pF is inverse to ESR and proportional to diode power rating, these ESD diodes have an ESR of about 120 ohms thus Vf=1.2 @50mA.

Also compare with ST's USBP* family of protection (<0.5pF) and read all,the App notes.!!